# resolving undefined references xcb

Tags: c++, c, undefined-reference, xcb

I can include items from `xcb/xcb.h`, but not items that are outlined in `/usr/include/xcb/randr.h`.

My preference is to use C++, but to help debug I also tried C which produced variations of the same error.

I am certain I am doing something incorrectly, but I am not sure where to start looking to resolve this. Thank you very much for reading, any suggestions?

## Example

#### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/randr.h>

int main()
{
    const xcb_setup_t                       * xsetup;
    xcb_connection_t                        * conn;
    xcb_screen_t                            * screen;
    xcb_window_t                              root_win;
    xcb_screen_iterator_t                     screen_iterator;
    xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_cookie_t   resources;

    // connect to Xserver
    conn   = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
    xsetup = xcb_get_setup(conn);

    // get the root window
    screen_iterator = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(xsetup);
    screen          = screen_iterator.data;
    root_win        = screen->root;

    // any function from xcb/randr.h fails with undefined reference.
    resources = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources(conn, root_win);
}
```

#### Compile

```sh
# gcc tries
gcc -Wall  main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`
g++ -Wall  main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`

# clang tries
clang++    main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`
clang      main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`
```

#### Result

`gcc`

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWR2GQL.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`clang`

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/main-d114b5.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources'
clang-7: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What's the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`?

Comment: `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb` returns `-lxcb`

Comment: Randr is in a separate library, probably called libxcb-randr.

Comment: But you need to link against it: `-lxcb-randr` in your link command.

Comment: Thank you very much, that resoled my issue. Sorry, I am very new to compiled languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xcb libraries are split up in several different packages; so it goes that you need to pull in both `xcb` and `xcb-randr` libraries, explicitly:

```
... `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb xcb-randr`
```

It's possible that your Linux distribution packages the randr library separately. Checking Fedora, it packages both xcb and xcb-rand in the `libxcb-devel` subpackage; but it's possible that your Linux distribution has a separate `libxcb-randr-devel` subpackage that you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much `n.m.` and `G.M.` .

I was not linking the `xcb-randr` .

Solution:

```sh
clang++ main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb` -lxcb-randr
```